# Is there a way to view what is being written on serial from a Python script without connecting a device?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, monitor

In short, I have written a Python program to write a series of commands to a serial device I'm working with, and I want to make sure they're working in the way I want them to.

Comment: If you expect to verify that the bits actually are shifted out of the UART at the specified baudrate, then something has to be connected to sample that electrical signal.  The simplest connection is probably a USB-serial adapter with appropriate interface, i.e. either RS-232 or TTL (5V or 3.3V).  Use a PC executing a terminal emulation program (in hex display mode if necessary) to view the output of the Python code.  Otherwise use an oscilloscope.

Answer (score 1):

For sure, no device connected means no response/nothing to read...

Did you consider trying a serial port sniffer, if you google for **serial port sniffer**, you'll find more than you need.
Connect any serial device and sniff what you send.

Comment: Yes a sniffer is a good idea. I can recommend wireshark: https://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: Do you know how to set one up with Visual Studio code? I apologize if this is a stupid question, I'm new to programming Python and using Visual Studio.